# Recommendations for project files/document storage tools (not source code and no videos)

Tags: file-management, project-management

I am looking at various options for project file/document management tools (not source code and no videos). My requirements being:

- Upload/download documents in the folder structure
- Share Documents
- Permissions and Access Security
- Lock documents for editing
- Version Control
- Recognize document template
- Basic workflows

I am confused between Microsoft SharePoint, Microsoft OneDrive, Microsoft Teams and Microsoft TFS (team foundation services). For the features listed above what would be the best option? Are there any other tool suggestions please?

Comment: What kind of files and what kind of project? Source code and massive video files will likely require a different tools.

Comment: not source code and no videos